# Aura Component: (lightning:input) Fire 'onclick' before the 'onblur' event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have the following code in the cmp file:

```
<lightning:input onchange="{!c.handleChange}" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" onblur ={!c.handleBlur}" />
```

**Issue:** I want the code to fire the 'onclick' first instead of the 'onblur'. Currently 'onblur' is fired first even if the 'onclick' fires parallelly.

**I've tried:** I've used settimeout on the handleBlur method, which works fine. However, I'm looking for a concrete solution. I can implement it using LWC if it's viable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not fire events "in parallel." There is only one execution context (aside from Workers, outside the scope of this answer), so events must be processed one at a time. Browsers are free to choose the order of execution of those events, leading to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17769005/2132791) (on Stack Overflow).

Depending on what you're trying to do in each handler, you might want to use Promise instead of `setTimeout`:

```
handleClick: function(component, event, helper) {
  Promise.resolve()
  .then($A.getCallback(
    function() {
      // Do your additional logic here
    });
}
```

`Promise.resolve` will wait until nothing else is happening, then continue with the logic found in the `.then` callback function. Do remember to use `$A.getCallback` if you need Aura to be active (e.g. if you plan on firing an event).